# PyQt and ListModel

Tags: pyqt

How can I fill a data list in a data listmodel with the content of a given path?

Here is what I'm trying to do :

```
class TestListModel(QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QAbstractListModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.testnames = []

    def load_docfiles(self):
        cfg = Config()
        for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(cfg.test_path, 'test_*.rst')):
            self.testnames = os.path.basename(filename)[5:-4]
            filepath = os.path.abspath(filename)
            print "load docfile", str(self.testnames)
        return str(self.testnames)

    def rowCount(self, index):
        return len(self.testnames)

    def data(self, index, role): 
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            cfg = Config()
            for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(cfg.test_path, 'test_*.rst')):
                self.testnames = os.path.basename(filename)[:-4]
                filepath = os.path.abspath(filename)
        return self.testnames

    def columnCount(self, index):
        pass
```

Another question is how can I load an html page (in a qwebview) associated with an item selected from my listview?

Thanking you!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misunderstanding the purpose of the `data` method in the Model classes in Qt.  Instead of reloading your data (in your case your list of file names), the `data` method should be mapping an index given by the associated `QListView` to an item in your `testnames` list.  For example,

```
def data(self, index, role):
    if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
        testname = self.testnames[index.row()]
        return testname
```

It looks like you want your `load_docfiles` method to store a list of file names in `self.testnames`.  You could rewrite it like this:

```
def load_docfiles(self):
    cfg = Config()
    for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(cfg.test_path, 'test_*.rst')):
        self.testnames.append(os.path.basename(filename)[5:-4])
        filepath = os.path.abspath(filename)
        print "load docfile", str(self.testnames)
```

Your class could then be called from your main application like this:

```
self.view = QtGui.QListView(self)
self.model = TestListModel()
self.model.load_docfiles()
self.view.setModel(self.model)
```

Comment: Thanks it works better but now when I want do:                 testName = self.model.data(item, role)                               it gives me :
    testname = self.testnames[index.row()]
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'row'

Comment: What is `item`?  `data` is expecting to be given an index and a role.  `index` should be a QModelIndex, but it looks like you are trying to pass a list.

Comment: item is the current test select on the list and here is the method to get it :                                                         def getSelectedTestName(self):
        item = self.list.selectedIndexes()
        print 'test selected', item
        return item

Comment: Then item is a list of all of the selected indexes?  You will need to loop over that list and provide `data` with the indexes one at a time.

Comment: I've found it was just a currentIndex() instead of the selectedIndex()